# :hover is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to web development, so although appreciated, I am not looking for critiques on "best practices", I realize this is not beautiful code, but I am not sure why the a:hover function is not working. it does indeed work for other parts of the code that are not included but I am not sure why this code will not work, any insight would be appreciated.

NOTE: There is no issue with the .css filepath or anything, all the other styles elements work just fine.

So with this question I have included two files, my .html file as well as my main.css file. I have removed any personal information and any code that is not pertinent to the actual issue.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: white;
}

html {
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.home {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.intropage {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#enterwebsite {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
  border: solid white 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

#enterwebsite:hover {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-size: 48px;
  color: black;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

.enterbutton-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 39.5%;
}

.enterbutton {
  text-align: center;
}

.backgroundimage {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("styles/images/SF2.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.backgroundimage img {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.9);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 30;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}

p {
  color: white;
  padding: 32px;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.logo h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1.0);
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 32px;
}

#logotop {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#logobottom {
  text-decoration: overline;
}

.logotext {
  justify-content: center;
}

.intro-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.menu {
  flex-grow: 70;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  z-index: auto;
}

.ul-menu {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}

.profilepic img {
  border: solid 2px cyan;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.topmenuitem {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="home">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="logocontainer">
        <a href="index.html">
          <div class="logotext">
            <h1 id="logotop">JOHN J</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="logotext">
            <h1 id="logobottom">JINGLEHEIMERSCHMIDT</h1>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="ul-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="topmenuitem" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="topmenuitem" href="home.html">Projects/code</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="topmenuitem" href="home.html">Music</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="topmenuitem" href="home.html">Websites</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="topmenuitem" href="home.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="topmenuitem" href="home.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-body">

  </div>
  <div class="intro-container">
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="profilepic">
        <img src="assests/profilephoto.jpg" alt="Profile Picture">
      </div>

      <h2>Welcome!</h2>
      <p>Hello, and <a href="home.html"> this is a test link </a> thank you for visiting. here is some text
        <br>
        <br>
        <br> here is some more text
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: where is the html element with the enterwebsite id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
z-index: -2;
```

at .home class

Your body has only one child tag with class home. In this case you shouldn't to set negative z-index. Negative z-index means that this element under the all others elements

Answer (score 0):

Yes Bro, I have debugged your code. 
Because of negative z index, your cursor is not detecting the link itself. Removing it, solves the problem. Please check the property properly that how you want to use it.

```
.home{
  position: relative;
 // z-index: -2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `z-index: -2` rule of the `.home` selector in your CSS
Then, wrap the `a` with `span`:
`<p>Hello, and <span><a href="home.html"> this is a test link </a></span> thank you for visiting.`.
And in CSS:

```
span:hover {
    //code n' stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove z-index: -2; from css file 
and for more information related to z-index property in CSS please visit this link
[CSS z-index property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)